# One-Hot-Encode only integers, slices( `:`), ellipsis( `...`), numpy.newaxis(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays ar valid indicies problem

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to solve below problem through one-hot-encode, but error occured, too.

I'm trying to make image classification(catching rectangle), and when I try to let it one-hot-encode, the error occured.
Before change into one_hot_label,
the labels like:

```
 'circle' 'circle' 'circle' 'circle' 'circle' 'circle' 'circle' 'circle'
 'pentagon' 'pentagon' 'pentagon' 'pentagon' 'pentagon' 'rectangle' ....
 'triangle' 'triangle' 'triangle' 'triangle' 'triangle' 'triangle']
```

I made T into`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ... , [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` because I have 5 kinds of figure.
But on `row[X[idx]] = 1`,
I got an error: 
`only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

```
def _change_one_hot_label(X):
    T = np.zeros((X.size, 5))
    for idx, row in enumerate(T):
        if(X[idx] == 'rectangle'):
            row[X[idx]] = 1

    return T
```

I don't know what should I do to solve this problem...

Please help me. Thanks.

=====================================================================

## TRYING TO SOLVE WITH ABOVE WAY. (ONE-HOT-ENCODE)

=====================================================================
I'm studying deep-learning.

I got an error: 'ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype('

I tried to solve it myself, but I need help.

I'm loading my image dataset with

```
data_list = glob('dataset\\training\\*\\*.jpg')

def load_label(data_list):
    labels = []
    for path in data_list:
        labels.append(get_label_from_path(path))
    return np.array(labels)
```

x_batch example: [[0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157 ... 0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157]
 ...
 [0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157 ... 0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157]]

t_batch example: ['circle' 'circle' ... 'circle' 'circle']

```
train_size = 3 # x_train.shape[0]
batch_size = 22
for i in range(242): # iters_num = 242
   batch_mask = np.random.choice(train_size, batch_size)
   print( t_train, batch_mask )
   x_batch = x_train[batch_mask]
   t_batch = t_label[batch_mask]
   grad = network.gradient(x_batch, t_batch) # error start position
```

When I try to get gradient, it flows `self.loss(x_batch, t_batch) # each parameter is x, t` ->

```
def loss(self, x, t):
        y = self.predict(x)
        return self.lastLayer.forward(y, t)

def forward(self, x, t):
        self.t = t
        self.y = softmax(x)
        self.loss = cross_entropy_error(self.y, self.t)
        return self.loss

def cross_entropy_error(y, t): 
    if y.ndim == 1:
        t = t.reshape(1, t.size)
        y = y.reshape(1, y.size)

    batch_size = y.shape[0]

    return -np.sum(t * np.log(y+1e-7)) / batch_size
```

And the latest line, `return -np.sum(t*np.log(y+1e-7)) / batch_size`,
I got an error: `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')`

I tried to change labels into a int for examples: 'circle' = 0, 'rectangle' = 1, but then my deep learning do not learn about it.

I don't know what I'm missing..
Can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the one hot encoding problem you can use the following function.

```
import numpy as np

label2idx = dict(rectangle=0, circle=1, pentagon=2, ..)

def _change_one_hot_label(X):
    T = np.zeros((len(X), 5)).astype('int32')
    for i in range(T.shape[0]):
        label = X[i]
        T[i, label2idx[label]] = 1

    return T

_change_one_hot_label(['circle', 'rectangle', 'rectangle'])
```

For the other question, as you are saying the variable `t` is a string array containing `['circle', 'rect' ..]` and you cannot multiply strings and numbers.

First, you should apply the one hot encoding function to `t`.

```
def cross_entropy_error(y, t): 
    # It is nota good practice, but you can place this instruction here
    # Maybe, if you have a 'batch preprocessor function' you should place it there
    t = _change_one_hot_label(t)

    if y.ndim == 1:
        t = t.reshape(1, t.size)
        y = y.reshape(1, y.size)

    batch_size = y.shape[0]
    return -np.sum(t * np.log(y+1e-7)) / batch_size
```